# Isolating Arduino from engine crankshaft position sensor circuit

Tags: arduino, analog, sensor

I'm trying to read engine RPM via analog (Arduino interrupt) so I don't have to request the CAN signal because requesting it digitally over OBD-II is too slow. We can read the engine RPM via the crankshaft position sensor. Right now, our digital solution takes about 4 code cycles to get the new engine RPM. We'd like to know it every cycle.

I understand we'll need to isolate the Arduino from the crankshaft position sensor signal so that we aren't introducing noise that affects the truck's ability to function as it would if we weren't tampering with it. I'm aware of a few ways to do this (opto-isolator, voltage follower and voltage divider). We have only implemented a voltage divider before but I'm curious if there's a more robust way to do this. The engine RPM is a safety critical signal. **So there's a 4th item which allegedly works and seems similar to a voltage divider... but I don't know what it's called and thus can't figure out how to design the components of the circuit** or decide if this solution works for me. **So I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out what it is**:

[Here's a similar stackexchange discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481239/inductive-crankshaft-position-sensor-voltage-drop-when-split-between-inputs) but no circuits are shown.
[This Arduino forum discussion](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/crankshaft-position-sensor-reading/379509/3) has a person who's trying to read the tach on his motorcycle. One user suggested they use the following circuit:

[image: see attached, red and black arrows were drawn by the OP trying to clarify how to wire this. Just calling that out because the original picture doesn't show]

My confusion is that this appears to be a voltage divider if I just look at R4 and R5. But then there 's resistors, R3 and R6, on the tachometer wires. **What could these be for?** Why wouldn't these values just be combined with R4 and R5? I'm not familiar with diodes, but I know one purpose for them is to provide a voltage drop. The person who suggested this circuit to OP says 'You could use some resistors and diodes to clamp the voltage between 0..5V'. Perhaps this is what D3 is for? D1 seems like it may be for forward biasing the signal but it seems like it's biased the wrong way if the intent is to keep the Arduino from sending noise to the ECU?

Or, if someone knows why the other options I mentioned or didn't mention would be more appropriate or more robust, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: R3 and R6 are current limiting resistors for the rail clamp diodes. That is also not an isolation circuit. That is a circuit to clamp spikes which is not the same as isolation.

Comment: `Right now, our digital solution takes about 4 code cycles to get the new engine RPM. We'd like to know it every cycle.` ... slow down your code

Comment: @jsotola I like the simplicity of the suggestion, but there are other things we need to read quickly. As the truck drives, many signals are updating so we want to know about them. Engine RPM is one of them. We're automating a manual clutch. This is the reason we want to know the engine RPM faster. Consider you knew the engine RPM every 5 seconds and were trying to shift. You'd stall and still be sitting there before you checked for the next RPM. Ideally, you'd know the engine RPM every .1 seconds or so while you let the clutch slip and engage.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for clarifying! I'll see what info I can find on those kinds of circuits.

Comment: @Bryon you can get the RPM reading only once per revolution of the engine ... that is many cycles of the arduino code ... if your code is unable to compute the RPM at every crankshaft rotation, then there may be something wrong with your code

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

We're reading it digitally over the OBDII network. Meaning we have to request it over the CAN network and wait for a reply to the request. We think the issue is that the priority of other messages of the CAN bus causes us to have to wait sometimes. 

But comparing the frequency range of the RPM signal assuming we knew it directly from the crankshaft position sensor:

The truck does 1000-3000 RPM during normal driving. That's 1000rpm*(1min/60sec)=16.7Hz and 3000rpm*(1min/60sec)=50Hz.

One cycle of the code is .056s. 17.9Hz.